# How to get currently playing video on Youtube?

Tags: python, browser

I am trying to make a Python script that gets the currently playing YouTube video but I can't find out how I can exactly make it. I know that some programs (and Windows itself) can get the currently playing content on the browser and actually even control it but I have no idea of how something like that can be achieved in Python.